# 1.5 GB in space used for system without installing any apps after using super su-me

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, rooting, internal-storage, system

Hello everyone I used to have kingroot installed on my device and for some reason I thought it will be better to have super su so I downloaded super su-me and as promised it did remove king root and installed super su but after that I found the available storage for my device going from 1.2 GB to 18mb and I found that space was used in system as I found that the space used for system files increased from 3.3 to 5 GB so what happened and how I can undo this and. Any solution will be appreciated

Things I have tried:
1-Factory reset(it removed super su and king root so I installed king root again and space of system remain bigger)

Answer (score -1):

Did you completely wipe everything with TWRP yet?

Also, what type of phone do you have?

I suggest [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com) for all of your questions, sounds like you may not have discovered it yet, since you are using Kingo Root.